# How do I ignore pending rspec tests in Rubymine?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubymine

I have many pending tests in my application, and they make it hard to view a failed test in Rubymine[image: rubymine].

Is there a way, either through rspec command line options or Rubymine settings, to disable running pending tests entirely?  Or at least not show them in the view?  I know of the button to not show passing tests, but that doesn't help with pending tests.

Answer (score 0):

Rspec 3.1?  Pending's meaning has changed... try skipped instead?

From: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-1/docs/pending-and-skipped-examples

> An example can either be marked as skipped, in which is it not
>   executed, or pending in which it is executed but failure will not
>   cause a failure of the entire suite. When a pending example passes
>   (i.e. the underlying reasons for it being marked pending is no longer
>   present) it will be marked as failed in order to communicate to you
>   that it should no longer be marked as pending.

Comment: We're still using RSpec 2.14 - doesn't look like skipped is in that version.